# How to test internal function into function in angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have one question for you guys.
It is any way to test internal function, I talk about successCallback and failureCallback;
Because hen I check code coverage, those functions are not covered.

```
onSubmitForm() {
    const name: string = this.newForm.controls.name.value;
    const successCallback = () => {
      this.popupService.popupSuccess();
    };
    const failureCallback = () => {
      this.popupService.popupFailure();
    };
      this.myservice.edit({ name, this.id }, successCallback, failureCallback);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this could work.

```
it('should call popupSuccess on success', () => {
  component.onSubmitForm();
  // get the 2nd argument
  const successCallback = mockMyService.edit.calls.mostRecent().args[1];
  successCallback();
  expect(mockPopupService.popupSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('should call popupFailure on failure', () => {
  component.onSubmitForm();
  // get the 3rd argument
  const failCallback = mockMyService.edit.calls.mostRecent().args[2];
  failCallback();
  expect(mockPopupService.popupFailure).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. You solved this problem.